# Cannot prove basic functions relying only on Implementations/Inlining

Tags: formal-verification, jml, key-formal-verification

I have this class Course. I can prove the passed(int i) method when I use the contract for getBar(), not without it. Besides the contract of getBar() is also proven. Why can't I prove passed with inlining? I tried both Key 2.8 and Key 2.7.

```
public class Course {

    /*@ spec_public @*/ private int bar;
    /*@ spec_public @*/ private int time =100;
    public  boolean strict= true;

    /*@ public  normal_behaviour
      @ requires this!=null;
      @ ensures  \result==bar;
      @ assignable \nothing;
      @*/
    public int getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }
    /*@ public normal_behaviour
      @ ensures  \result==(getBar()<=i);
      @*/
    public boolean passed(int i) {
        return this.getBar()<= i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [KeY](https://key-project.org) verification engine can be used to verify [JML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Modeling_Language) annotated Java programs. (Mostly automatically, but interactive theorem proving is possible).

It works modularly. This means that every method is considered individually. Your method `passed` calls `getBar`, but `getBar` may actually be overriden in a subclass of Course – one which may be added later. KeY verifies programs using the "open program" paradigm which means that any extension (addition of classes) of the program cannot invalidate existing proofs.

*Therefore:* Inlining is not possible for this invocation since the method may be overridden.

*Solutions*:

1. Make the class `final`. (No overriding then)
2. Make the method `getBar` `final` (Again, no overriding)
3. Make the method `getBar` `private` (Again, no overriding)
4. In the GUI use the `Options > Taclet Options` options to set the option `methodExpansion` to `noRestriction`. (Change from "open program" to "closed program" and allow method expansion everywhere.)